# Update deeply nested array of objects using redux toolkit reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am new in redux. So pardon any silly mistakes.

I have deeply nested array of objects like the below structure:

```
const initialState = {
    schedules: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role_id": 1,
            "rules": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "module_id": 16,
                    "remark_id": 2,
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I need to update `remark_id` inside the rules array inside a schedule object.

I have tried this, but no idea why it is not working:

```
updateRemark: (state, action) => {
    const { remark_id, rule_id, schedule_id } = action.payload
        const schedule = state.schedules.find(schedule => schedule.id == schedule_id)
        if (schedule) {
            const rule = schedule.rules.find(rule => rule.id == rule_id)
            if (rule) {
                rule.remark_id = remark_id
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I have followed the guide from official docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#updating-nested-data

Comment: Are you using Immer, like the page you linked to is referring to? If not, you're mutating `rule.remark_id` so redux won't know to update. If you're using Immer, have you logged all the results of your `.find()` calls to ensure they're found? And what does "not working" mean?

Comment: As the document says they use immer internally, so I think the package itself manages immer. when I logged the `.find()` calls it logs some `Proxy`. By "not working" I mean the property is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be:

```
const index = schedule.rules.findIndex(rule => rule.id == rule_id)
schedule.rules[index].remark_id = remark_id
```

Whithout this:

```
const rule = schedule.rules.find(rule => rule.id == rule_id)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. The `remark_id` property has been updated. I am curios to know why the destruction didn't work?

Comment: Because at this moment a variable is created that is torn off from tracking

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Yesss, I really forgot that. Anyway, thanks a lot.